# Unable to control parallel execution for cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, maven-surefire-plugin, testng-dataprovider

I am unable to control the treads from dataproviderthreadcount.
For example if we have 4 scenario and I run my script, it execute all 4 scenario's parallelly. Doesn't matter what dataproviderthreadcount value I gave in the pom for maven-surfire.

Below are the snapshots.

**POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testParallerRun</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <cucumbertestng.version>5.6.0</cucumbertestng.version>
        <cucumberjava.version>5.6.0</cucumberjava.version>
        <mvncompiler.version>3.8.1</mvncompiler.version>
        <javarelease.version>11</javarelease.version>
        <mvnsurefire.version>3.0.0-M5</mvnsurefire.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumbertestng.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumberjava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${mvncompiler.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>${javarelease.version}</release>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${mvnsurefire.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                                <value>2</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Runner Class:**

```
package com.test.runner;


import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;


@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "json:target/reports/json/result.json",
                "html:target/reports/html/result.html"},
        strict = true,
        features = {"src/test/resources/"},
        glue = {"com.test.stepdef"},
        tags = {""}
)

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    @Override
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

**Feature 1:**

```
Feature: test 1

  Scenario: 01
    Given Print "01"

  Scenario: 02
    Given Print "02"

  Scenario: 03
    Given Print "03"

  Scenario: 04
    Given Print "04"
```

Please let me if anyone know how to control the number of threads rather than let Testng decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem with TestNG per se here.

The `dataproviderthreadcount` attribute that you have set in your pom file is going to be applicable and relevant only when you are running your test via `mvn clean test`.

If you are trying to run this test class from within the IDE (IntelliJ or Eclipse for that matter) its not going take affect.

Here's a test class that I created which is powered by a data provider ( For the sake of simplicity I have intentionally kept cucumber out of the equation )

```java
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AppTest {

  @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
  public void shouldAnswerWithTrue(int i) {
    System.err.println("Running on [" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "]");

  }

  @DataProvider(name = "dp", parallel = true)
  public Object[][] testData() {
    return new Object[][]{
        {1},
        {2},
        {3},
        {4},
        {5},
        {6}
    };
  }
}
```

Here's the command line output when I run `mvn clean test`

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ testng_playground ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.rationaleemotions.AppTest
Running on [15]
Running on [14]
Running on [15]
Running on [14]
Running on [14]
Running on [15]
[INFO] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.62 s - in com.rationaleemotions.AppTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Thanks Krishnan Mahadevan. I was missing the point it works only when we use mvn clean install

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the exact same. As Krishnan mentioned, the dataproviderthreadcount in pom.xml works only when you run **mvn test** but without any parameter. If you want to specify which suite xml to run, you will need to add **-Ddataproviderthreadcount=2** in command line as well. For example, "**mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=suite.xml -Ddataproviderthreadcount=2 test**"

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, exactly what I was looking for. I'm now using `-Ddataproviderthreadcount` to control thread count when executing from the terminal or from the IDE (just adding this in the configuration in IntelliJ).